# how to alter a referenced table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I created two tables `product_type` and `product` its script is as below:

```
create table product_type
(
  product_type_id integer constraint product_type_pk primary key,
  name varchar2(10) not null
);


create table product
(
  product_id integer constraint product_id_pk primary key,
  product_type_id integer constraint products_fk_product_types references product_type(product_type_id),
  product_name varchar2(30),
  description varchar2(50),
  price number(5,2)
);
```

Now suppose I rename my first table `"product_type"` to `"product_types"`

```
alter table product_type rename to product_types
```

then what will be its impact in second table because I used a foreign key there which references `product_type` which is now `product_types`

**What do I have to alter in my second table now?**

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle takes care of the second table in the database: if you look at the foreign key details in SQL Developer or similar tool you will see that the constraint now references PRODUCT_TYPES.  There is nothing for you to do.

However, your **script** is now out of date - if you want to use that script again somewhere you need to fix all references to PRODUCT_TYPE in it.

Comment: yes I checked its sql in sql Developer and you are right....

it is 

 CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."PRODUCT" 
   ( "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
 "PRODUCT_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
 "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
 "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
 "PRICE" NUMBER(5,2), 
  CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PRODUCT_ID")
  CONSTRAINT "PRODUCTS_FK_PRODUCT_TYPES" FOREIGN KEY ("PRODUCT_TYPE_ID")
   REFERENCES "SYSTEM"."PRODUCT_TYPES" ("PRODUCT_TYPE_ID") ENABLE
   )

Comment: @Andrews you wrote "However, your script is now out of date - if you want to use that script again somewhere you need to fix all references to PRODUCT_TYPE in it."  can you explain it, please

Comment: @Ravi, well if you were to run that script again it would create a table called PRODUCT_TYPE again, not PRODUCT_TYPES as you require.

Answer (score 1):

There is no effect on the main table.
oracle handle all change of the refernces table.